# New Thunderbird Plugin: Custom Menu in Message Display Toolbar

Tags: plugins, thunderbird

I'm new to Thunderbird plugin development, I would like to add a new menu to the message display toolbar with some options

In my manifest.json, I have already configured a menu using the following configuration, as outlined in the [Thunderbird WebExtension API documentation](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/messageDisplayAction.html):

```
 "message_display_action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_ctaMailSummarize__",
    "theme_icons": [
        {
            "dark": "images/bot-icon-light-64.webp",
            "light": "images/bot-icon-dark-64.webp",
            "size": 64
        },
        {
            "dark": "images/bot-icon-light-32.webp",
            "light": "images/bot-icon-dark-32.webp",
            "size": 32
        },
        {
            "dark": "images/bot-icon-light-16.webp",
            "light": "images/bot-icon-dark-16.webp",
            "size": 16
        }
    ],
    "type": "menu"
},
```

This configuration successfully adds a new menu:

[image]

However, I have been unable to add new options; the new menu appears empty.

I haven't found any useful documentation, but I assume I need to use the [messageDisplay API](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/messageDisplay.html), anyway it's unclear to me how to connect my previous configuration in the manifest.json with the API.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add items to Thunderbird's menus, you need to use the [menus API](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/menus.html).

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "SuperMenu",
    "description": "No description",
    "version": "0.1",
    "message_display_action": {
        "default_title": "SuperMenu",
        "type": "menu"
    },
    "permissions": ["menus"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
main();

async function main() {
    const contexts = [browser.menus.ContextType.MESSAGE_DISPLAY_ACTION_MENU];
    await browser.menus.create({ contexts, title: 'Foo' });
    await browser.menus.create({ contexts, title: 'Bar' });
}
```

To handle a click event, add an onclick property to the object passed to [menus.create()](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/menus.html#create-createproperties-callback) or use [browser.menus.onClicked](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/menus.html#onclicked).
For more information on the available parameters, please refer to the corresponding [documentation](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/menus.html#create-createproperties-callback).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, it works.

Just one point: I had to add an ID field, otherwise the new entries didn't appear in the menu:

`await browser.menus.create({ id: "fooId", contexts, title: 'Foo' });`

Thanks again, bye.